# Evil: How do I see the partial command I've been typing?

Tags: evil

Suppose I am in command mode, and I am in the process of typing `3dd` to delete three lines. How can I make evil mode show the (partial) command I have typed so far?

In other words, is there an evil mode equivalent to vim's `set showcmd`?

Comment: Does https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29216/how-to-get-keystrokes-displayed-in-the-echo-area-immediately answer your question?

Comment: @drRobertz I tried adding `(setq echo-keystrokes 0.1)` to my config file. When trying to do `3dd` to delete three lines, `C-u 3-` is shown when `3` is pressed, but that disappears when `d` is pressed.